# Firebase Cloud messaging not pushing Notification on chrome, but working with other browsers after May2, 2023

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, browser, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Firebase in my angular app, everything was working fine but suddenly push notifications stopped on chrome. I search solution but found that "chrome://gcm-internals/" tell socket connections where It was showing "connection state : waiting for Backoff"
I update chrome but nothing worked. I tried on different machine but had same issue. I reported to FCm suppor and they ask to try FCm sample web app. I configured that app but faced same issue

Finally I uninstall chrome and reinstall latest version and it started working.
Now my question is why update chrome to latest version (without uninstalling and reinstalling) did not work.
Is there any solution for this ?

I have tried
empty cache of browser (chrome)
deleting gcm store folder
changing machine
trying with FCM sample web app

Comment: I have the same problem as of August of 2023

Answer (score -1):

It seems the issue is in browser settings. There are a lots of limitation while using push notifications. I implemented Firebase realtime database for my app and that fulfill all my requirements and reliability.
So I will suggest you to implement Firebase realtime database